# Dialog "cancel" button linked to escape key

Tags: applescript

I have a bit of AS that opens a dialog box and prompts a user for an input, with button options of "cancel" and "send" ("send" is the default button). As it's the default button, "send" activates when I hit the enter/return key on my keyboard. I would like to have "cancel" activate when I hit the escape key on my keyboard. Is there a way to link a keyboard key with a button? I'm looking for a coded solution as opposed to an application setting solution because this piece of AS will be run by another application.

Any help is appreciated, example code is below!

```
set returnedThings to (display dialog ":message:" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"cancel", "send"} default button "send")
    set theMsg to text returned of the returnedThings
    set theBtn to button returned of returnedThings
    if theBtn is "send" and theMsg is not "" then
        -- do application specific tasks
    end if
```

Answer (score 1):

`Cancel` is linked to the ESC key automatically if it’s capitalized.

Comment: Brilliant. It works now, and I feel quite silly. Thanks for you help!